# Strange vue warn: `beforeDestroy` has been renamed to `beforeUnmount`

Tags: vuejs3

Well, I have this warning in the browser console:

```
[Vue warn]: `beforeDestroy` has been renamed to `beforeUnmount`.
```

at

This is weird, because I have not `beforeDestroy` anywhere and I have the latest versions of the packages in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.1.0",
    "three": "^0.123.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "v-calendar": "^3.0.0-alpha.3",
    "vue": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-dk-toast": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-material-design-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.4",
    "vue-socket.io": "^3.0.10",
    "vue-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.1.11",
    "vue3-quill": "^0.2.1",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.11",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.6.0"
  }
```

What could be wrong? I searched for the same problem but I only found this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8224 , which doesn't help.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: actually vue3 has released. Many things have changed. BeforeDestroy Lifecycle hook has been renamed to beforeUnmount... all lifecycle hhoks are here: (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: OK but I have Vue3, that's what I don't understand...

Comment: You wnated to create project with vue2? Your package.json requests exact version of vue.js. And this version is not the 2nd

Comment: No, I'm on full VueJS 3.0.

Comment: Probably, one of your dependencies is not for vue3 then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I figured its because `vue-socket.io` is not compatible with Vue3. Below is my solution.

1. update to [`vue-3-socket.io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-3-socket.io), which is a Vue 3 compatibility version of `vue-socket.io` (though it still not perfectly compatible with Vue3)
2. then open the file `node_modules/vue-3-socket.io/dist/vue-socketio.js`
3. search for `beforeDestroy` and replace it with `beforeUnmount`

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. It's sad that you can't just use the original vue-socket.io library.

Comment: If you want to automate the "edit this file in node_modules" part, you can use [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have "all packages at highest version" is very different from "all the packages I'm using are compatible with Vue 3" ....its clear one of the packages is definitely NOT compatible with Vue 3...